# Convert this sum to normal expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, systems-of-equations

If I have a sum like this: 
$$2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^i(3^{n-i}-1)$$ How do I convert it so that I can lose the sum. For example if it was 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}n$$ 
then the result would be 
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
Is there a general principle how to do this, for example like for geometric sums?

Comment: You are here for about $4$ months now and still have not done any effort to use  [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This while almost all of your questions were edited by others to make them look better. Let that change please.

Comment: Also note that $\sum_{i=0}^n n = n + \cdots + n = (n+1)n$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n i = 0+1+\cdots+n = \frac{n(\color{red}{n+1})}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general principles are the rules of arithmetic operations, operator precedence rules and the linearity of the summation-operator $\sum$. Some of the *[general identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#General_identities)* of the summation operator are often useful.  Based upon this information you might  be able to provide an explanation of the  steps below.

> We      obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^i\left(3^{n-i}-1\right)}&=
> 2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(3^n-3^i\right)\\
> &=2\cdot3^n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1-2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^i\\
> &=2\cdot 3^nn-2\cdot\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}\\
> &=2\cdot 3^nn-3^n+1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=3^n(2n-1)+1}
> \end{align*}